# Roll-up Summary fields not Recalc on import

Tags: roll-up-summary, import, dbamp

We use DBAmp to import records from another system.  Everything works fine except for when creating a new record.  **The record does not roll-up via the summary field on it's parent**.  Any ideas or other information that might be helpful to help me solve this problem?

Comment: do you see an #Error or just wrong numbers in the summary field on the master record?

Comment: @rao No error.  It's just the wrong numbers on the master numbers.

Comment: drphil - I know this is 2 years old, but what was the solution? I have the same issue in my org today.

Comment: I believe that the operation was running in parallel as opposed to serial and was causing record locks on the data.  I believe the issue was on the DBAmp end to make that change.  You might need to do a google search on how to make that change.  Welcome to StackExchange and please note that your answer here is going to get deleted soon since it is not a true answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is upon any DML of children records of a Master-Detail relationship should kick of the asynchronous recalculation of any roll-up summary fields on the master record.  Checking the Master Object, a recalculation is is still processing if there is a little purple icon next to the roll-up summary field.

If I am mistaken above,  a work-around is to simulate your own roll-up summary by (1) creating a field on the Master and (2) writing a trigger on the Child that calculates the roll-up value if the field-to-be-rolled-up changes.

The work-around isn't too difficult to write, but it's not the desirable solution -- the Master-Detail should already be doing this!

My guess is that you are processing a lot of records causing a lengthy recalculation.  If true, then the recalculation should occur eventually.  If false, this issue has to have been documented somewhere before -- though that "Force a manual recalculation" option may be there for a reason.

Doc:  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US

"Roll-up summary fields may take up to 30 minutes to recalculate"

---

### Update

Check out this doc on Bulk API and search for "Roll-up summary":

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes

I bet your 3rd party software is using Bulk API,  and maybe the ordering of how you're upserting records is causing "lock contention" with the Master records hence causing a roll-up summary failure.

Comment: Yea, the problem is that days go by and they don't recalc.  I really didn't want to go the trigger route but I'm prepared to if I need to.

Comment: With a trigger, just a heads up that it might be beneficial to use an @future to recalculate the roll up so you get another execution context to work in

Comment: Added an update

Comment: Thanks! I read through that document and it looks like running in parallel as opposed to serial could cause record locks on the data.  I have to wait until our SQL admin is in tomorrow to find out if he is executing the special command that makes it run in parallel instead of serial.