# Can you force a recalc of fields via Apex?

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary

Is there a way via code to do what this button does?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me say first that forcing RSF recalculations incurs a performance hit. You *shouldn't* need to do it programmatically.

That said, each of these actions will trigger a recalc. I believe you can do each of these through MD API (it's not Apex though, I know). Source: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US

- Changing the roll-up summary definition (such as the object, function, or field being aggregated)
- Changing the expression of a formula field referenced in a roll-up summary field
- Replacing picklist values for picklist fields referenced in the roll-up summary filter
- Changing picklist record type definitions
- Changing currency conversion rates
- Changing price book entries

(But if you have a reproducible case where you can predict you'll need a forced recalc, I'd very much like to hear about it.)

Comment: My other question I created explains it: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46061/can-you-force-a-recalc-of-fields-via-apex/46070#46070

Comment: I assume you meant this one: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46037/roll-up-summary-fields-not-recalc-on-import. Hmm, I wonder if DBAmp is doing something other than a plain insert. If I were you I'd file a case with them, if possible.

Comment: O yea that one. We tried that and they don't really know whats going on and didn't give any good ideas to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe updating any child record should kick of the asynchronous recalculation of the roll-up summary.

Comment: but would that be for all records or just the parent record of that child?

Comment: Updating any child record should do it.  SF might do a ISCHANGED(field_to_be_rolled_up__c) check though.

Comment: Yes, unfortionately it's not.  The issue seems to be when new children are created though.

Comment: Try a test:  update a parent then update a child and see if anything goes